# Python: how to linearly baseline each peak in a set of peaks

Tags: python, baseline

I need help writing code that would allow me to baseline each peak in a set of peaks (enthalpy vs. time isothermal titration calorimetry data).

The data is created by the ITC instrument in this fashion  (where '@#' signifies the start of a peak and the data are listed below as time [seconds], enthalpy [ucal/s], and temperature [deg. C but unnecessary as it is usually held constant]):

```
@0
2.00,13.585249,25.00761
4.00,13.585438,25.00699
6.00,13.585557,25.00688
8.00,13.585472,25.00804
@1,6.0000
302.00,13.607173,25.00958
304.00,13.607608,25.00931
306.00,13.607758,25.00965
```

There are well over 100 points per peak (I've shortened it above), and I'd like to incorporate a linear equation to zero each enthalpy value in each peak so I may integrate each peak to produce a binding plot. I'd welcome any help/advice; thank you!

Comment: Is your problem more reading in the values in an appropriate format or in fitting a model to the values or do you want to accumulate the values?

Comment: What do you mean by "allow me to baseline each peak" or "to zero each enthalpy value". These 2 phrases are unclear to me, and maybe for others who do not have your (chemical?) background as well (jargon). Also, have you tried anything already?

Comment: By *baseline*, do you mean to find the minimum value of the 2nd column (enthalpy) for each group of readings for a given peak?

Comment: Thank you all for your help; I apologize for being unclear. Penn State's Huck Institute provides a much simpler explanation of the instrument's purpose and the data produced than I ever could: http://www.huck.psu.edu/facilities/calorimetry-up/guides/itc.

Comment: To answer your questions, I have the data I need, enthalpy (y values) and time (x), in two lists of arrays (each set of lists corresponding to one peak you'll notice on the webpage I provided). The instrument, upon completing an injection, monitors the change in enthalpy (produced when one protein comes into contact with its binding partner [heat of binding]). It does so by quantifying the power necessary to return the sample's temperature back to where it was before injection. Unfortunately, the "recalibration" of this temp is not always perfect, so the enthalpy vs time peaks often drift

Comment: If you were able to answer your own question, you can (should) post that as an answer and accept it rather than edit it into the question.  That way other people can see that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it. Thank you to those who replied! I will leave this here to anyone who may need to baseline peaks with a linear fit in the future (assuming the first point and last 40 points will suffice in a decent fit line like it does in ITC):

```
#defining function to calculate baseline of peaks in x vs y graph
def calc_baseline(x,y):   
    zeroed_y=[]   
    for n in range(len(y)): 
        line_y=array(y[n][0:1]+y[n][-41:-1])
        line_x=array(x[n][0:1]+x[n][-41:-1])
        p=scipy.polyfit(baseline_x,baseline_y,1)
        baseline_y=array(x[n])*p[0]+p[1]
        zeroed_y.append(baseline_y)
    return zeroed_y

#defining function to zero baselines of peaks in x vs y graph, assuming number_injections is a known integer
def zero_baseline(number_injections,y,zeroed_y):
    zeroed_y_lists=[]
    for i in range(0,number_injections+1):
        zeroed_y=y[i]-zeroed_y[i]
        zeroed_y_lists.append(zeroed_y)
    return zeroed_y_lists
```